# how to assign first match and second match?

Tags: python

I have a lines that I split :

```
['Time      : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit0: 19359560-19359561 step 1', 'Expect    : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit0: XX', 'Acquired  : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit0: 00', 'Time      : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit1: 19359560-19359561 step 1', 'Expect    : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit1: XX', 'Acquired  : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit1: 00', '']
```

and I want to grab certain word from the line which is :

```
Acquired  : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit0: 00
Acquired  : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit1: 00
```

I'm using re.search function to match these line and I'm getting these:

```
searchObj.group()  =  Acquired  : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit0:0
searchObj.group(1) =  0
searchObj.group(2) =  0
status[0] ==  0
searchObj.group()  =  Acquired  : tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit1:0
searchObj.group(1) =  1
searchObj.group(2) =  0
status[1] ==  0
```

how can I append the first match and second match together? because what I want to do is I need the status[0] and status[1] gives 1 for passing value or else it will throw these value into failed value

Below are my codes :

```
for line in lines:
    searchObj = re.search(r'^Acquired\s+:tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit(\d): (\d)', str(line))
    if searchObj:
        print "searchObj.group()  = ",  searchObj.group()
        print "searchObj.group(1) = ", searchObj.group(1)
        print "searchObj.group(2) = ", searchObj.group(2)
        print "status[" + searchObj.group(1) + "] ==  " + searchObj.group(2)
```

Comment: The input looks like you read an entire file into memory and then split on newlines. Perhaps a better approach is to simply open the file and iterate over the filehandle, processing one line at a time as you read them. That also avoids the silly empty string at the end.

Comment: I'm not getting any match if I didn't split it

Comment: It's hard to refactor your code without seeing it. I'll add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily collect the matches into whatever data structures make sense to you. For example:

```
match_lines = []
tap_tuples = []
for line in lines:
    searchObj = re.search(r'^Acquired\s+:tap/stap_tap2gpsb/SBMSGRSP/status/bit(\d): (\d)', str(line))
    if searchObj:
        match_lines.append(line)
        tap_tuples.append((searchObj.group(1), searchObj.group(2)))
print('\n'.join(match_lines))
print(';'.join(tap_tuples))
```

By the by, if you are fetching these lines from a text file, you might want to process them one by one at the same time:

```
with open('file.txt') as handle:
     for line in handle:
        ...
```

If this is inside a function, maybe `yield` a result each time you find a match if you want the calling code to process them one by one. The next call to the function will `yield` the next match from the still-open filehandle until the input file is consumed.